# how to change ownership of hive table/database

Tags: hadoop, permissions, hive, hdfs

I have some tables in `test` database in `HIVE` that were created by another user.

I am trying to move these tables to another database called `events`

I have tried like below

```
alter table test.123 rename to events.123
```

But I am receiving `permission denied` error because the table `123` has been created by another.

```
1) How can I move this table?

2) How can we change the owner of the table to other user's?

3) Or How can we change ownership of all tables of a database to another user?

4) What is the best scenario where we don't need to worry about permission on Hive tables?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try following with superuser

```
ALTER (DATABASE|SCHEMA) database_name SET OWNER [USER|ROLE] user_or_role;   -- (Note: Hive 0.13.0 and later; SCHEMA added in Hive 0.14.0)
```

If your Hadoop cluster is Kerberos enabled then there is no way you can change the ownership with non-super user account. If this would have been possible then there is no use of Permissions.

Comment: Just a [link to a source](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-AlterDatabase).